# Ventana modal con 02 vistas bootstrap con c# mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, bootstrap, mvc

Alguien me podría ayudar, tengo una aplicación mvc c# de tipo maestro detalle, para agregar detalle en la vista principal cargo una ventana modal (bootstrap) que contiene otra vista (no partial view) selecciono una opción de un dropdownlist, cuando le doy en aceptar regresa al formulario y lo agrega correctamente PERO me borra los datos de los text box y de los multiline text de la cabecera (vista principal).
Estuve investigando y la solución sería utilizar Jquery Ajax pero sólo encuentro ejemplos donde llaman al controlador y utilizan una sola vista y en mi caso utilizo 2 vistas, la principal (cabecera) y la que carga en el modal.
Ayuda amigos.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Disculpen, soy nuevo en esto.

Comment: no te disculpes, no hay problema, solo lee los links que te pase, arregla tu pregunta agregando toda la informacion usando el boton [edit] y Bienvenido.